# Branch line and integrals. Not finding the correct answer.

Tags: complex-analysis

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{ln x}{x^{3/4}(1+x)}dx$$

Integrating the real axis from 0 to infinity, so go around a big circle and close from - infinity to 0, around 0 close the path with a little circle.

$x = r$ along the real axis and Re>0. $I =  \int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{ln x}{x^{3/4}(1+x)}dx$

Along the big circle, the integral vanishes.

along the real axis and Re>0, $ \int_{\infty}^{0} \frac{e^{i \pi /2 }ln r}{r^{3/4}(1+r)}dr = - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i \pi /2 }ln r}{r^{3/4}(1+r)}dr = -iI$

Along the little circle it will diverge ...

Along a circle around minus one, it diverges too. So what should i do? I can't see any other point .

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use Fourier series instead of complex analysis, we can derive a more powerful result.

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143229/doing-the-integral-int-0-infty-fracxs-11x-dx-frac-pi-sin-pi-s/3143281#3143281), we use Fourier series to show that for $0 < \alpha < 1$
$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac {1}{x^{\alpha}(1+x)}dx = \frac \pi {\sin(\pi \alpha)}$$
So taking the derivative w.r.t. $\alpha$ yields, for $0<\alpha < 1$,
$$\boxed{\int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\ln(x)}{x^{\alpha}(1+x)}dx = \frac {\pi^2\cos(\pi \alpha)} {\sin^2(\pi \alpha)}}$$
Evaluating at $\alpha = \frac 3 4$ gives
$$\boxed{\int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\ln(x)}{x^{\frac 3 4}(1+x)}dx = -\pi^2 \sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is another possible approach based on the fact than we have the antidericative
$$\int \frac{ \log (x)}{x^{a}(x+1)}\,dx=$$ $$-\frac{x^{1-a}}{(1-a)^2}\Bigg[\, _3F_2(1,1-a,1-a;2-a,2-a;-x)+(a-1) \log (x) \, _2F_1(1,1-a;2-a;-x) \Bigg]$$ which could also write
$$-x^{-a} \left(x \Phi (-x,2,1-a)+(-x)^a \log (x) B_{-x}(1-a,0)\right)$$

Using the integration bounds
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{ \log (x)}{x^{a}(x+1)}\,dx=\pi ^2 \cot (\pi  a) \csc (\pi  a)\qquad \text{if} \qquad 0 <a <1$$