# How would one find the value of this summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would one go about finding the value of this summation? ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2+1}$

Comment: Is there any reason to imagine that it has a pleasant closed formula?

Comment: Since this is a Leibniz series then the series converges and the sum is bounded by $|S|\leq \frac{1}{2}$ (the first element). But other than that im not sure you can get a number.

Comment: @lulu I saw on Wikipedia that ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+a^2}}$ for ${a \in \mathbb{R}}$ had a nice closed form, so I just wondered if the alternating one had any known closed form

Comment: I believe it should be equal to$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2+1}-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2+(1/2)^2}=\frac12\left(1-\frac{\pi}{\sinh{(\pi)}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [verify](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818734/fourier-series-of-cosax) that if $s\notin \mathbb Z$,
$$\cos{st} = \frac{\sin{\pi s}}{\pi s} \left [1+2 s^2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \cos{n t}}{n^2-s^2} \right ]$$

So if $t=0$, $$1 = \frac{\sin{\pi s}}{\pi s} \left [1+2 s^2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} }{n^2-s^2} \right ]$$
which gives, with $s=ia$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} }{n^2+a^2} = -\frac{1}{2a^2}\left(\frac{\pi i a}{\sin(\pi i a)}-1\right) $$

$$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} }{n^2+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{\pi}{\sinh(\pi)}\right)}$$